# Excel Debt Payoff Calculator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a weekly Excel debt retirement sheet with one column for each week. The header row has weekly dates (Friday payday). There are four columns at the front of the weeks, one for the name of the creditor, one for the day of month to make the payment, one for the amount owed, and one for the payment amount. Payments are made monthly. **The payments should be zero after the debt is paid off.** Example: for a debt to be paid in four months, there will be four payments four weeks apart and they will then end.

Each row has a separate creditor.

I made a good start by having Excel show the payment date by =IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(G$1),MONTH(G$1),$C4)>=F$1,DATE(YEAR(G$1),MONTH(G$1),$C4)<G$1),$E4,0) where Row 1 has the weekly dates, C4 is the date due (number, day of month), and E4 is the payment amount. To keep things simple, I am excluding any payments on the 29th, 30th and 31st dates.

PROBLEM --> How do I get the payment amount be set at zero after the debt is paid off? I've tried =(SUM($F5:INDEX(5:5,COLUMN()))) in a separate row and it correctly shows the total amount paid off in columns to the left. But I cannot use that to make the payment zero after payoff is complete because I keep getting circular logic errors.

TIA!

[Completed Excel Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggWdZ.jpg)